# 3 points meteorology stations

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation

I want to extract meteorological data of a point which are 3 meteorological stations around it. I found that ArcGis has the capability to do it by interpolation. 
My essential data is wind speed , wind direction and cloud cover
which interpolation method or any other method is useful for my case?

Comment: How far apart are the stations? Wind data don't interpolate usefully for distances greater than a few kilometres due to terrain and roughness effects.

Comment: There is a free/open source wind model that can model the effect of terrain on wind fields.  You can use a csv file to input weather station data.  You need a digitial elevation model of the area of interest, and you can download that using the program.  See:

http://windninja.firemodels.org

Comment: the stations distances are about 40 kilometers and the interpolating methods that I've done by ArcGis was not logic. and the other problem is that my data is hourly and I couldn't extract sufficient information from its output. I'll try the model you suggested.
thank you

Answer (score 1):

[This document](http://www.snap.uaf.edu/attachments/Interpolation_methods_for_climate_data.pdf)  could help you choose the interpolation method, but i would suggest [SAGA GIS](http://www.saga-gis.org/en/index.html) as alternative for ArcGIS for its strong support for interpolations.

Comment: thank you so much. I'll read the document and try SAGA GIS too.